# regex to only replace certain patterns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

In the following example, using Python 3.8, I am looking to replace only the comma in `NUMBER(38,0)` with a pipe.

```
MISC1 VARCHAR, MISC2 VARCHAR, NUMBERS NUMBER(38,0), MISC3 VARCHAR
```

The expected outcome would be

```
MISC1 VARCHAR, MISC2 VARCHAR, NUMBERS NUMBER(38|0), MISC3 VARCHAR
```

The `NUMBER(38,0)` could appear anywhere in the list so I cannot specify the 3rd comma, for example, and `NUMBER(38,0)` could appear several times. In addition, I need to be able to do this even if the numeric values inside the brackets changes such as `NUMBER(24,2)`.

I have not been able to come up with a working solution that does not replace all the other commas as well so I am reaching out to the expert in the hive to see if someone else more knowledgeable then me can figure this out.

The RE string I have been using is

```
([A-Z])\w+\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\)
```

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: If you need to change where ever it says `NUMBER(xx,x)`... it seems to me you need to search for `NUMBER(` and then find the next `)` after that and replace the comma inside of those indexes. In the long run, that's probably an easier to maintain solution than a regex here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

sampleStr = 'MISC1 VARCHAR, MISC2 VARCHAR, NUMBERS NUMBER(38,0), MISC3 VARCHAR NUMBER(24,1)'

sub_sampleStr = re.sub(r'(\(\d+)(,)(\d+\))', r'\1|\3', sampleStr)
print(sub_sampleStr)
```

**Output:**

```
print(sub_sampleStr)
MISC1 VARCHAR, MISC2 VARCHAR, NUMBERS NUMBER(38|0), MISC3 VARCHAR NUMBER(24|1)
```

Comment: This works and I love the simplicity. Can you please explain the r'\1|\3' part of the code to me so I can learn to be better?

Comment: Ya so that’s the grouping. Similar to the other solution, I have group 2 as the “,” part.

Comment: Group 1 is the (38  Group 2 is the ,   Group 3 is 0). So it’s basically saying keep group 1 and group 3 and put the pipe between them (and I don’t put group 2 in the substitution)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, for the specific example you've shown:

```
import re

yourstr = 'MISC1 VARCHAR, MISC2 VARCHAR, NUMBERS NUMBER(38,0), MISC3 VARCHAR'
newstr = re.sub(r'([A-Z]+\([0-9]+),([0-9]+\))', r'\1|\2', yourstr)
```

It's similar to the expression you showed in your question. Essentially, we split the entire capture `NUMBER(38,0)` into two capture groups: `NUMBER(38` and `0)`, separated by a comma, which we replace by a `|`.

---

If you wanted to replace an arbitrary number of commas within parentheses, then you'd probably want to use a lambda replace instead:

```
newstr = re.sub(r'[A-Z]+\((?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+\)', 
                lambda m: m.group(0).replace(',', '|'), 
                yourstr)
```

which just looks for an entire token like `NUMBER(38,5,6,0)` and replaces `,` with `|` *only inside that token*.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks!